# vtkImageReslice 3D rotation questions

Tags: c#, 3d, vtk

I am trying to rotation a 3D object with VTK as I rotate a knob control. Here is how I implemented it (in C#). However, when I rotate the control knobs, the 3D object in the screen was gone. I am not sure what happened, but since before vtkImageReslice was added, everything was fine, I suppose it was the culprit.

Some of the code I think relevant:

```
private vtkAxesActor axes; 
        private vtkCamera camera; 
        private List<vtkImageChangeInformation> changeFilters; 

        //private vtkTIFFReader reader; 
        private vtkImageAppendComponents componentAdaptor; 
        private List<vtkStringArray> fileNameArrays; 
        private List<vtkImageFlip> flippers; 
        private vtkRenderWindowInteractor iren; 

        // these two arrays specify the color range for the components specified by the array indexes 
        private int[] lowerThreshold = { 0, 0, 0, 0 }; 
        private List<vtkTIFFReader> readers; 
        private vtkRenderer renderer; 
        private vtkRenderWindow renderWindow; 
        private RenderWindowControl renWindowControl; 
        private int[] upperThreshold = { MaxGrayScaleLevel, MaxGrayScaleLevel, MaxGrayScaleLevel, MaxGrayScaleLevel}; 
        private vtkVolumeProperty volProperty; 
        private vtkVolume volume; 
        private vtkFixedPointVolumeRayCastMapper volumeMapper; 
        private vtkOrientationMarkerWidget widget; 


        public void setDefaultColorMapping() 
        { 
            if (volume == null) 
            { 
                MessageBox.Show("No volume exist"); 
                return; 
            } 
               // vtkVolumeProperty volProperty = volume.GetProperty(); 

            vtkColorTransferFunction colorFunctionA = vtkColorTransferFunction.New(); 
            colorFunctionA.AddRGBSegment(0, 0, 0, 0, MaxGrayScaleLevel, 1, 0, 0); 
            volProperty.SetColor(0, colorFunctionA); 

            vtkColorTransferFunction colorFunctionB = vtkColorTransferFunction.New(); 
            colorFunctionB.AddRGBSegment(0, 0, 0, 0, MaxGrayScaleLevel, 0, 1, 0); 
            volProperty.SetColor(1, colorFunctionB); 

            vtkColorTransferFunction colorFunctionC = vtkColorTransferFunction.New(); 
            colorFunctionC.AddRGBSegment(0, 0, 0, 0, MaxGrayScaleLevel, 0, 0, 1); 
            volProperty.SetColor(2, colorFunctionC); 

            vtkColorTransferFunction colorFunctionD = vtkColorTransferFunction.New(); 
            colorFunctionD.AddRGBSegment(0, 0, 0, 0, MaxGrayScaleLevel, 0.5, 0.5, 0); 
            volProperty.SetColor(3, colorFunctionD); 

            //volProperty.SetInterpolationTypeToNearest(); 
            //renWindowControl.RenderWindow.Render(); 
        } 

        public void setToDefault() 
        { 
            if (null == renWindowControl.RenderWindow) 
                return; 

            volumeMapper.SetBlendModeToMaximumIntensity(); 
            volumeMapper.SetCropping(1); 
            volumeMapper.SetCroppingRegionFlagsToSubVolume(); 

            //setDefaultColorMapping(); 
            //setDefaultOpacityfunction(); 

            widget.SetOutlineColor(0.93, 0.57, 0.13); 
            widget.SetOrientationMarker(axes); 
            widget.SetInteractor(renWindowControl.RenderWindow.GetInteractor()); 
            widget.SetEnabled(1); 

            double[] rotX = { 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 }; 
            double[] rotY = { 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 }; 
            double[] rotZ = { 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 }; 
            double[] center = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 }; 

            _reslicer.SetResliceAxesDirectionCosines(DoubleArrayToIntPtr(rotX), DoubleArrayToIntPtr(rotY), DoubleArrayToIntPtr(rotZ)); 
            _reslicer.SetResliceAxesOrigin(DoubleArrayToIntPtr(center)); 
            _reslicer.SetInterpolationModeToLinear(); 
            _reslicer.SetOutputDimensionality(3); 

            iren = renWindowControl.RenderWindow.GetInteractor(); 
        } 

        private void SetupScene() 
        { 
            renderer = renWindowControl.RenderWindow.GetRenderers().GetFirstRenderer(); 
            renderer.RemoveAllViewProps(); 

            if (_isZStackDataExist == true) 
            { 
                // volumeMapper.SetInputConnection(componentAdaptor.GetOutputPort());         
                _reslicer.SetInputConnection(componentAdaptor.GetOutputPort());               

                volumeMapper.SetInputConnection(_reslicer.GetOutputPort()); 
                //volumeMapper.Update(); 

                volume.SetMapper(volumeMapper); 
                //volume.SetOrigin(DataExtentX / 2, DataExtentY / 2, DataExtentZ / 2); 

                renderer.AddVolume(volume); 
                renderer.ResetCamera(); 
                camera = renderer.GetActiveCamera(); 
            } 

            renderer.SetBackground(0, 0, 0); 
            //renderer.GetActiveCamera().Zoom(3); 
            //deleteAllVTKObjects(); 
        } 

        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
        public void updateXRotation() 
        { 
            if (false == IsVolumeRendererReady) 
                return; 

            if (null != _reslicer) 
            { 
                double[] rotX = { 1.0, 0.0, 0.0};   
                double[] rotY = { 0.0, Math.Cos(DataXRotationDegrees), -Math.Sin(DataXRotationDegrees)};   
                double[] rotZ = { 0.0, Math.Sin(DataXRotationDegrees), Math.Cos(DataXRotationDegrees)}; 
                double[] center = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 }; 

                _reslicer.SetResliceAxesDirectionCosines(DoubleArrayToIntPtr(rotX), DoubleArrayToIntPtr(rotY), DoubleArrayToIntPtr(rotZ)); 
                _reslicer.SetResliceAxesOrigin(DoubleArrayToIntPtr(center)); 
                _reslicer.SetInterpolationModeToLinear(); 
                _reslicer.Update(); 
            } 

        } 

        static IntPtr DoubleArrayToIntPtr(double[] rotDoubleArr) 
        { 
            // Initialize unmanaged memory to hold the array. 
            int size = Marshal.SizeOf(rotDoubleArr[0]) * rotDoubleArr.Length; 

            IntPtr rotIntPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size); 

            try 
            { 
                // Copy the array to unmanaged memory. 
                Marshal.Copy(rotDoubleArr, 0, rotIntPtr, rotDoubleArr.Length); 
            } 
            catch 
            { 
            } 

            return rotIntPtr; 

            //finally 
            //{ 
            //    // Free the unmanaged memory. 
            //    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(rotIntPtr); 
            //} 
        }
```

Any one has any idea how I can make this work? To rotate a 3D object with vtkImageReslice, or should I go for something else? It seems there are not many C# example how to rotate a 3D. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you trying to rotate the object on screen, or rotate the voxels inside the image data? What you're trying to do is for the second. If you just want to visually rotate, you can just use actor transforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to view object from different angle, then change the camera view is one of the options. Here is an example of rotating a 3D object around its y axis for -angle:

```
public void RotateToRight()
{           
       double cos = Math.Cos(angle);
       double sin = Math.Sin(angle);

       double[] rot = { cos, 0, -sin, 0,
                          0, 1,    0, 0,
                        sin, 0,  cos, 0,
                          0, 0,    0, 1};

       transform.SetMatrix(DoubleArrayToIntPtr(rot));
       camera.ApplyTransform(transform);
       renderer.ResetCamera();
       renderer.GetActiveCamera();
       ForceWindowToRender();
}
```

Here is the original view:
[image]

Here is the view after the function is executed once, in which case the object rotated around its y axis for -angle (- means count clockwise)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Easier and more intuitive maybe is to use the methods RotateX, RotateY and RotateZ of the class vtkTransform.

A code example in java:

```
private void rotate(double angle, int axis) {
    vtkTransform t = new vtkTransform();
    bw.GetTransform(t);

    switch(axis) {
        case X:
            t.RotateX(-angle); 
            break;
        case Y:
            t.RotateY(-angle);
            break;
        case Z:
            t.RotateZ(-angle);
            break;
    }

    ren.GetActiveCamera().ApplyTransform(t);
}
```